# What is the intended usage of DEVICE_INT_ATTR?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, sysfs

I would like to expose some settings of my device via sysfs. If I understand it right, a driver can have multiple devices, so there should be one instance of the settings variable per device. This should be easy enough using `DEVICE_ATTR` macro.

Checking the sources I noticed there is also `DEVICE_INT_ATTR` and other with different type. I wonder what is the intended usage, as they use `device_show_int` functions that get pointer to device, but [*don't actually use it*](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.3/source/drivers/base/core.c#L2147):

```
ssize_t device_store_int(struct device *dev,
             struct device_attribute *attr,
             const char *buf, size_t size)
{
    struct dev_ext_attribute *ea = to_ext_attr(attr);
    int ret;
    long new;

    ret = kstrtol(buf, 0, &new);
    if (ret)
        return ret;

    if (new > INT_MAX || new < INT_MIN)
        return -EINVAL;
    *(int *)(ea->var) = new;
    /* Always return full write size even if we didn't consume all */
    return size;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(device_store_int);
```

I searched kernel sources for those macros, and it seems that they work with a global variable. For example `DEVICE_INT_ATTR` is used in [drivers/base/core.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mcheck/mce.c#L2266) for `mca_cfg.tolerant`:

```
static DEVICE_INT_ATTR(tolerant, 0644, mca_cfg.tolerant);
```

but the `mca_cfg` varaible is actually [global](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mcheck/mce.c#L73), not tied to a device:

```
struct mca_config mca_cfg __read_mostly = {
    .bootlog  = -1,
    /* ... */
    .tolerant = 1,
    .monarch_timeout = -1
};
```

which makes it look like a driver (not device) attribute.

I also checked [commit that adds these macros](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?h=v5.18-rc2&id=ca22e56debc57b47c422b749c93217ba62644be2) but it did not help me much.

Answer (score 2):

You correctly take that `DEVICE_INT_ATTR` and other macros from that family are for "global" attributes, which `store` and `show` methods doesn't use `dev` parameter.

If you want to define attribute, which can be bound to **several devices**, then you could write your own `store` and `show` methods which gets information about the value from `dev`.

E.g. by having device

```c
struct my_device
{
  struct device base;

  int repetition;
};
```

you could expose its `repetition` field in the attribute using following `show` method:

```c
// Shows value of 'repetition' field of my_device.
static ssize_t repetition_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
  // Obtain pointer to the real device structure.
  struct my_device* my_dev = container_of(dev, struct my_device, base);
  return sprintf(buf, "%d\n", my_dev->repetition);
}
```

Structure of such attribute could be initialized using `__ATTR` macro:

```c
static struct device_attribute repetition_attr =
  __ATTR(repetition, S_IRUGO, repetition_show, NULL);
```

---

### Making "generic" attributes

Assume your device struct contains many `int` fields, which you want to expose via attributes:

```c
struct my_device
{
  struct device base;

  int repetition;
  int counter;
  int value;
};
```

In that case you could generalize attribute definition, so you don't need to create many `show` (and `store`) functions.

E.g. you could store **offset** of the exposed field in your attribute structure:

```c
struct device_bounded_attr
{
  struct device_attribute base_attr;
  size_t field_offset;
};

// Initializer for struct device_bounded_attr
//
// - real_device_type - type of the actual device structure
// - device_member - member of type 'struct device' in the actual device structure
// - field_member - member in actual device structure which you want to expose as attribute.
#define BOUNDED_ATTR(name, mode, show, store, real_device_type, device_member, field_member) { \
  .base_attr = __ATTR(name, mode, show, store), \
  .field_offset = offsetof(real_device_type, field_member) - offsetof(real_device_type, device_member)
}
```

Using this field, you could rewrite `show` method as follows:

```c
// Shows value of integer field, stored in device.
static ssize_t bounded_attr_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
  // Obtain pointer to the real attribute structure.
  struct device_bounded_attr* bounded_attr = container_of(attr, struct device_bounded_attr, base_attr);
  // Having offset of the field, calculate pointer to it
  int field_ptr* = (int*)(((char*)dev) + bounded_attr->field_offset);
  return sprintf(buf, "%d\n", *field_ptr);
}
```

So attributes can be declared as follows:

```c
static struct device_bounded_attr repetition_attr =
  BOUNDED_ATTR(repetition, S_IRUGO, bounded_attr_show, NULL, struct my_device, base, repetition);
static struct device_bounded_attr counter_attr =
  BOUNDED_ATTR(counter, S_IRUGO, bounded_attr_show, NULL, struct my_device, base, counter);
static struct device_bounded_attr value_attr =
  BOUNDED_ATTR(counter, S_IRUGO, bounded_attr_show, NULL, struct my_device, base, value);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but while it confirms to me that using DEVICE_INT_ATTR is not the way to go, the rest does not address my question. I can write my own  `store` and `show` methods. I don't know why the DEVICE_INT_ATTR macros exist at all. Or, in other words, in which situations the macros would be the right thing.

Comment: Probably, the one who write `DEVICE_<type>_ATTR` macros expect them to be widely used in kernel code for expose some variables as files. But they are appeared not so useful. Not only because of "global" property of such attributes, but also because there is no possibility to "preprocess" variables before showing or storing values. E.g. [store_int_with_restart](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.3/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mce/core.c#L2526) function needs to protect the variable's setting with a mutex.